# Just generated jhipster app - Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

Tags: webpack, jhipster

I am trying to run a [jhipster](https://www.jhipster.tech/creating-an-entity/) project I just generated. I generated with version 5.0.0-beta.1 and with these on the front end:
-React
-Sass transpiler
-i18n support

For some reason, I am getting an error when I try to run the newly generated app:

```
ERROR in chunk main [entry]
app/[name].bundle.js
Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
```

I tried uninstall and reinstall jhipster with no success. My `webpack` version is `3.10.0` and `yarn` is `1.3.2`. I am running on top of MAC. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually this is a bug reported by so many users in the below thread.

Meanwhile they fix this you can give a try for several possible solutions which may work for you.

Solution 1: add `type: "javascript/auto"` to the rule in web config file.

Solution 2: Changing to just utf-8 may solve sometimes.

Please follow below thread for more info.

https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/7082

Comment: Which web config file are you talking about?